# Maintaining highlight for selected item in fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a layout with two fragments.  The left hand fragment is a ListFragment using a SimpleCursorAdaptor, the right hand one is populated with details about the item selected from the list in the left fragment.  I'm trying to figure out how to make sure the selected item from the ListFragment *stays* highlighted until another item in the list is selected.

After some research I got as far as trying to use `android:background="@drawable/item_selector"` I can changes the colors for the different states, but none of them seem to persist.  I thought that selected would... it just seems logical that your selected item remains the selected item until you select a different one.

I even tried using `v.setSelected(true);` in my clickhandler hoping it might maintain the state, but that didn't work either.

Is there a state I'm missing?  I looked through the dev docs and nothing else seemed appropriate...

**item_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

I'm not sure what other code might help, so feel free to ask for whatever else you might think necessary.

Comment: I know this is old, but doesn't the selector need an element that has no qualifiers in the event none can be matched?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was in the android documentation after further research (two parts of the documentation really).

First, in touch mode there is no selected or focused state.

Second, by default, listviews are set to a choice mode of none (meaning that no item in the list can have a chosen state).  All I had to do was change the choice mode (it could be single or multiple, I only needed/wanted single) by adding this:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Then I used the choice state in my selector XML (translates to the `activated` state):

```
<item 
 android:state_activated="true" 
 android:drawable="@color/blue" />
```

Apply that in the row layout xml file as the background:

```
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

My chosen item now appears with a blue background until a different item is chosen.

Note that this (android:state_activated) requires Android API 11 or later.

Comment: android:state_activated needs at least API level 11

Comment: I tried this and my API is > 11 but it does not seem to work. I am also using a ListFragment and given that Master/Detail View is such a fundamental thing, it's amazingly difficult to get it to work. Did you maybe forget a tiny detail that's part of your solution? Because just the part you posted, doesn't seem to be enough to make it work for me.

Comment: @Zainodis, I've updated my answer.  I really thought it was apparent, but maybe not.  You have to apply the style to the row layout in the XML.

Comment: @Barak Thanks for the update :) - figured it out by looking at other samples. Maybe it actually was apparent and I overlooked it, but thanks for clarifying :) !

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add **state_focused** too to make it feel like selected or highlighted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I gave it a try, but still no luck.  :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked very nice for me in the `ListFragment`, but I think it works only for Android 4.0 and up. I created a simple layout for the list item with `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator` (in case of Android below 4.0 you need to ceate the similar one in drawables):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/double_view_margin" />
```

And then, just create a simple `ArrayAdapter` using this layout and set the choice mode to single:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> labelsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.item_simple_list_item, R.id.list_item_text, labels);

setListAdapter(labelsAdapter);

getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

After that you can hightlight the necessary item with `setItemChecked` method:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(final ListView l, final View v, final int position, final long id) {
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```