# Highlight selected Item in Master Detail Flow

Tags: android, fragment, master-detail

I'm using `default` Master/Detail Flow theme in Android Studio. The problem I saw in that layout is when I select item from left side, it does not get highlighted, like the Navigation Flow theme. 
Because of that, I get confused with which item I selected before. I tried with adding this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023904/maintaining-highlight-for-selected-item-in-fragment). but I couldnt implement it in this flow.

This is the behaviour I'm expeting im my app. Can someone guide me on how to do that?

[image]

Comment: without code nobody would help you, sorry

Comment: @piotrek1543 there is nothing to code. if you create new project on android studio. and select Master/Detail Flow.  just run it

Comment: It seems when they updated the master/detail flow template it no longer does selected item highlighting. It might have something to do with the switch from listview to reyclerview and lack of choice modes. Regardless, the template is broken without this IMO.